# How to use events like @blur on custom Vue components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am building a custom component that works like an input field with validation and I cant get @Change, @blur... etc to work on it just like it would on an input field.

This is the template of the component:

```
// callback-date-multiselect.html

<div>
  <multiselect
    v-if="hasOptions"
    v-model="selected"
    :options="optionsList"
    :name="name"
    :searchable="false"
    :allow-empty="false"
    :maxHeight="1000"
    track-by="date"
    label="label"
    placeholder="Bitte wählen"
    key="select"
  >
  </multiselect>
  <input
    v-if="!hasOptions"
    type="text"
    pattern="[0-9]*"
    inputmode="numeric"
    v-model="selected"
    v-input-mask="'date'"
    v-suppress-aria-invalid
    key="input"
    :name="name"
  />
</div>
```

And this is the component being used inside another component:

```
// example-form.component.html

<callback-date-multiselect
      :initial="callbackDateDay"
      :name="'callbackDateDay'"
      v-model="callbackDateDay"
      @blur="v$.callbackDateDay.$touch"
      @change="v$.callbackDateDay.$touch">
</callback-date-multiselect>
```

I get the following error:

```
Component emitted event "blur" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onBlur" prop.
```

Comment: You're using Vue3 or 2 here? Give a try to `defineEmits`: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits

Comment: I am using a package called 'vue-facing-decorator' to create class components which has a built in @Emits property, which I am guessing should work similar to 'defineEmits' but I am not sure how to set up the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a custom component and in that case you have to manually specify what should `@blur` do, which is called binding events to components through emits

So, you basically just need to specify that the `@blur` will emit an event then you add this

```
export default {
    ..
    ..
    emits: ['event_name'],
    methods: {
        blurHandler() {
            this.$emit('event_name')
        },
    },

};
```

then you would call this in the parent component and specify what it does

Hope that was simple enough and that it was helpful!!

Comment: So in the template I would do '@blur="blurHandler"'?

Comment: at the template where you use this component add '@event_name=function()' and this function is then in the methods of this template script as a method which does exactly what you want